# How is an array with a length declared within a class? [Visual Basic]

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

I want to declare an array with a set length as a `Public Property` within a class, and fill the array with zeroes so that `squares(0) = squares(5) = squares(42) = 0`, etc.

What I tried:

```vb
Public Class Board     
    Public Property squares(width*height) As Integer 
End Class
```

What I expected:

```vb
squares = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

What actually happened:

`Error BC36759: Auto-implemented properties cannot have parameters`

Comment: Just be aware that the versions using an AUTO-IMPLEMENTED PROPERTY give you both a "get" and a "set" property. Why does this matter?...because with a "set" property, you can COMPLETELY REPLACE the backing array with a different array, possibly of different dimensions, potentially putting your Board class into a state that makes no sense for your problem. This is why I and some others showed a READONLY property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Board
    Public Property squares As Integer()

    Sub New(ArraySize As Integer)
        ReDim squares(ArraySize)
    End Sub

End Class
```

When you create the class, you create it like:

```
MyBoard = New Board(64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation, if your size is hard-coded:

```
Public Class Board

    Private width As Integer = 5
    Private height As Integer = 10
    Private _squares(width * height) As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property squares As Integer()
        Get
            Return _squares
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: @DaveDoknjas  Sure you can! You can't use "_squares" if you have an AUTO-IMPLEMENTED property called "Squares". I'm not using an auto-implemented property, I've manually coded that property, so it is allowed. Try it out...

Comment: Right - thanks - made the change.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler variation, maintaining the auto-property and no private field:

```
Public Class Board
    Private Const width As Integer = 5
    Private Const height As Integer = 10

    Public Property squares() As Integer() = New Integer(width * height) {}
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
Public Class Board

    Private _board() As Integer = New Integer() {}
    Public ReadOnly Property Squares() As Integer()
        Get
            Return Me._board
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(width As Integer, height As Integer)
        Array.Resize(Me._board, width * height)
    End Sub
End Class
```